# Are there any good examples for how to use the accelerometers in iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, uikit, accelerometer

I think that there are some issues with the earth Gravity, so I wonder if there are any examples where the accelerometers work by subtracting these.

Comment: I very seriously doubt that the sensitivity of the iPhone accelerometers are going to be high enough to detect "issue" with earth gravity (for any range of "issues" that normal humans are likely to encounter).

Comment: The "issue" is that gravity is an acceleration, and so the accelerometer detects it.  If the phone is steady, the accelerometer shows 1G acceleration downward. That's great for knowing which way is up (down) but it's not something you want to factor into something like shake detection.

Comment: If you make the assumption that the iPhone doesn't rotate significantly while being shaken, then gravity shouldn't matter, because you're looking for change in forces, and gravity is an unchanging force.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to assume much about how people will hold their phones, especially when it's so easy to avoid that assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(It's too bad you can't file a bug with planet Earth to fix its Gravity issue!)

There are several examples listed under "Related sample code" in the [UIAcceleration Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAcceleration_Class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html).

As that doc states, a value of 1.0 represents roughly +1g.  So if you point the iPhone straight up in portrait orientation, you should see roughly <0, -1, 0>.  As you rotate the phone around, the magnitude of the acceleration vector `sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)` should stay around 1.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's AccelerometerGraph demo includes sample code that implements a high-pass filter-- effectively filtering out the effect of gravity.  It's pretty simple to just grab it and modify to suit your needs.